# Special Characters Are Read Wrong - File I/0

Tags: c, linux, gcc, file-io, special-characters

This code reads a file byte per byte in order to duplicate it:

```
 fplain = fopen("plaintext", "rb");
 fcypher = fopen("cyphertext", "wb");

 for(j = 0; j < Nb; j++){
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            if(feof(fplain))
                break;              
            fread(&in[i][j], sizeof(unsigned char), sizeof(unsigned char), fplain); 
            fwrite(&in[i][j], sizeof(unsigned char), sizeof(unsigned char), fcypher);
    }
 }
```

The problem is that the input file contains special characters that are not being read correctly:

```
2Cö¨Z011¢à74
```

It seems that the end of the file is detected before, the result in the output file is:

```
2Cö¨Z011
```

I use "rb" mode in the fopen() function.

Comment: Which value contains variable `Nb`?

Comment: @Howard 4 (int). The input file has 16 characters written in hex ascii.

Comment: Thus, depending on the encoding of your file (and on the size of char of your compiler), you may read not enough bytes.

Comment: @Howard The compiler is gcc, and the file has no extension.

Comment: looks like your input is written using 16bit characters - you are reading 4x4x8bit so you get 8 characters

Comment: `2Cö¨Z011¢à74` are **twelve** characters.

Comment: I'm confused - is the input as described in the question or is it 'hex ascii'. And you might want to clarify what 'hex ascii' means to you, because I have a feeling you might be using a different meaning that I do, which is that the file contains only the characters '0'-'9', 'a'-'f', 'A'-'F', maybe with whitespace/newlines.

Answer (score 0):

A byte encoded in hex occupies two bytes. To produce 16 characters you have to read 32 bytes from the file; if you read 16 bytes you can produce only 8 characters.

On the other hand, if by "16 hex encoded chars" you mean that the file contains only 16 bytes, you can't expect to read 12 characters (24 bytes). In that case the last 4 characters in your expected output are probably random garbage produced by a buggy program, and there's no way to reproduce them reliably.

Comment: Here: "The input file has 16 characters written in hex ascii." I guess you could interpret that as saying there are 16 hex characters, which would mean the file contains data for 8 characters, but that contradicts the expectation of being able to read 12 characters from the file.